# Odoo allow administrator to see all record in tree view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

In tree view I show record where is user_id = uid and for that use:

```xml
<field name="domain">[('user_id.id','=',uid)]</field>
```

I need allow administrator to see all record without domain filter.

Any simple solution?

Comment: I recommend the use of `ir.rule` aka access rules. There are some easy to understand examples in the `sale` module of odoo for the model `sale.order`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using following method.

Remove domain from the **action** & **Inherit search method in python file**.

```py
from openerp import models,fields,api,_
from openerp.exceptions import Warning
from openerp.osv import  expression
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID

class mail_message(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.message'

    def _search(self, cr, uid, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None,
                context=None, count=False, access_rights_uid=None):
        """ Override that adds specific access rights of mail.message, to restrict
        messages to published messages for public users. """
        if uid!=SUPERUSER_ID:
            args = expression.AND([[('user_id', '=',uid)], list(args)])
        return super(mail_message, self)._search(cr, uid, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order,
                                                context=context, count=count, access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid)
```

> When action will execute _search will be called, in which you can check
>   if user_id is **SUPERUSER_ID** then do not add domain or add domain.

This may help you.

Comment: You should write _search method in your class, I have just given example of mail.message, you should write this method in your classs ex: test.g

Comment: Your example work fine, but is it possible on frontend eg. http://localhost:8069/mypage  disable filter, only for backend tree view I need _search function.

Comment: I am not clear with your question..Can you describe ?

Comment: Your example work fine for backend (tree view). Now I'm create new controller and on http://localhost:8069/mypage display all data from model admin can see all but other user see only your record  ('user_id', '=',uid). I do not need restriction for frontend odoo only for backend.